# How can I mount a subvolume on BTRFS from Arch in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, mount, btrfs

I have switched from Arch to Ubuntu. The installation was quite easy, however I cannot mount a BTRFS subvolume. When mounting with `sudo mount -o subvol=markus /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/backup/` I get the following error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3,  
missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: Always check /var/log/syslog and dmesg for more information. "Why can't I mount the subvolume?" we can not tell you more than what the error says: wrong fs type, bad option bad superblock. missing codepage or missing helper program. You need to go through the logs regarding this message and see if you can narrow it down. Is the helper for nvme  installed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
    sudo apt install btrfs-progs -y
```

https://linuxhint.com/install-and-use-btrfs-on-ubuntu-lts/

Then retry your mount command.  Please be sure to specify the *type* of filesystem you want to mount.   In this case, *-t  btrfs*  is going to be the type.

```
    sudo mount -t btrfs -o subvol=markus /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/backup/
```

Answer (score 1):

dmesg show:

> BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p3): 'markus' is not a valid subvolume

I have now simply mounted the partition and can access the directory. I assumed that I have to mount it via BTRFS. Anyway, I can now access the data again!

Thanks for the tip with dmesg. I'm fairly new to Linux and still have a bunch of things to learn.

Have a nice week